# Why is the ?? operator not working in Moq setup method

Tags: c#, null, moq

Could someone explain to me, why this doesn't work?

---

```
builder.Setup(b => b.BuildCommand(query ?? It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(command);
```

If `query` is `null`, `BuildCommand` will be passed `null`, and not `It.IsAny<string>()`

Instead, I have to do this:

```
if(query == null)
    builder.Setup(b => b.BuildCommand(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(command);
else
    builder.Setup(b => b.BuildCommand(query)).Returns(command);
```

---

Is it related to the delegate?

---

EDIT - Complete example

```
public static void ReturnFromBuildCommand(this Mock<IQueryCommandBuilder> builder, IQueryCommand command, string query = null)
{
    if(query == null)
        builder.Setup(b => b.BuildCommand(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(command);
    else
        builder.Setup(b => b.BuildCommand(query)).Returns(command);
}
```

Then I can call it like

```
var command = new Mock<IQueryCommand>();
var builder = new Mock<IQueryCommandBuilder>();
builder.ReturnFromBuildCommand(command.Object);
```

Or

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM Persons;";
builder.ReturnFromBuildCommand(command.Object, query);
```

Depending on whether I care about the parameter or not.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the thought process here. Just use `It.IsAny<string>()`. What are you trying to achieve and why? provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added some context, Nkosi. Wasn't sure it was needed.

Comment: Ok the added context improves my under standing. My next question now would be what does the `BuildCommand` expect. Are you setting up two different methods overloads or one method that can take both arguments?

Comment: Can you show the definition of the method being mocked. ie `BuildCommand`

Comment: @Nkosi `IQueryCommand BuildCommand(string query);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Setup` method of the mock takes in an expression, which the Moq framework then deconstructs to determine the method being called and the arguments to it.  It then sets up an interceptor to match the arguments.

You can see this in the `Mock` source:

```
    internal static MethodCallReturn<T, TResult> Setup<T, TResult>(
        Mock<T> mock,
        Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression,
        Condition condition)
        where T : class
    {
        return PexProtector.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (expression.IsProperty())
            {
                return SetupGet(mock, expression, condition);
            }

            var methodCall = expression.GetCallInfo(mock);
            var method = methodCall.Method;
            var args = methodCall.Arguments.ToArray();

            ThrowIfNotMember(expression, method);
            ThrowIfCantOverride(expression, method);
            var call = new MethodCallReturn<T, TResult>(mock, condition, expression, method, args);

            var targetInterceptor = GetInterceptor(methodCall.Object, mock);

            targetInterceptor.AddCall(call, SetupKind.Other);

            return call;
        });
    }
```

Here `args` is of type `Expression[]`.

(reference: https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Mock.cs#L463)

This `args` array is passed into the constructor for the Moq type `MethodCallReturn` as the parameter `arguments`.  That constructor (via the base class `MethodCall`) generates an argument matcher using `MatcherFactory.Create`. (reference: https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MethodCall.cs#L148)

This is where things start to get interesting!
In the MatcherFactory.Create method, it tries to determine the type of the argument's Expression by looking that the `Expression.NodeType` and/or checking it against known types, such as `MatchExpression` (which is what something like `Is.Any<string>()` would be).
(reference: https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MatcherFactory.cs#L54)

So let's take a step back. In your specific case, the code `query ?? Is.Any<string>()` is compiled down to an expression itself -- something like this ugly mess (as generated by the dotPeek decompiler):

```
(Expression) Expression.Coalesce((Expression) Expression.Field((Expression) Expression.Constant((object) cDisplayClass00, typeof (Extension.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0_0)), 
 FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle(__fieldref (Extension.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0_0.query))), 
(Expression) Expression.Call((Expression) null, (MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(__methodref (It.IsAny)), new Expression[0]))
```

And that's what the first argument looks like. You can rewrite your code to better express what Moq sees, like this:

```
    public static void ReturnFromBuildCommand(this Mock<IQueryCommandBuilder> builder, IQueryCommand command, string query = null)
    {
        Expression<Func<IQueryCommandBuilder, IQueryCommand>> expressOfFunc = commandBuilder => (commandBuilder.BuildCommand(query ?? It.IsAny<string>()));

        var methodCall = expressOfFunc.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        var args = methodCall.Arguments.ToArray();
        var nodeType = args[0].NodeType;

        builder.Setup(expressOfFunc)
            .Returns(command);

    }
```

If you place a breakpoint, you can see that the value of `nodeType` is `Coalesce`.  Now, go back and change it to just use `query`, and `nodeType` becomes `MemberAccess`. Use `It.IsAny<string>()`, and `nodeType` is `Call`.

This explains the differences between the three approaches and why it's not acting like you expected.  As for why it triggers on `null` is not clear to me, to be honest, but whatever matcher comes out of `MatcherFactory.CreateMatcher` seems to think `null` is a valid value for your mock configuration.

Comment: Awesome answer, Thank you!